# Is it possible to get all your stats to 100 in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is this possible and if so what is the quickest way to achieve it? I've been trying to upgrade everything as I farm for experience I cant see me hitting 100 on everything before the level cap is reached. Any ideas?
I don't include mods or glitches in my gaming on Skyrim btw.

Comment: Here is a link that contains both legit and some exploits on how to quickly level each skill. http://www.g4tv.com/thefeed/blog/post/718771/skyrim-how-to-level-your-skills-through-exploits-not-quite-cheating-but-kinda/

Comment: How is this a duplicate it is in now way the same question as what is the level cap :S

Comment: Seeing this again makes me want to play Skyrim again haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Levels are defined by skill levels, so you reach level 81 when you've got (almost) all skills to 100. However you can now reset skills that reach 100 back to 15, to gain more experience (levels) from getting the skill to 100 again.

Some skills can be trained with minimal effort:

- Alchemy - with enchanted gear to create very high value potions
- Illusion - Muffle can be cast anywhere
- Alteration - Detect Life when in a town
- Smithing - crafting high-value jewelry

Comment: Is this a patch on PS3?

Comment: @NathanTaylor I didn't see the ps3 tag, but yes the patch is available for ps3: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Patches_(Skyrim) April 21st.

Comment: This makes me wonder how is the stat reset explained... a voluntary rock to the head?

Comment: Sneak is probably the most minimal effort there is.  Crouch by a stationary guard and walk into a wall.